# Inserting images side by side in a figure

Tags: graphics

I am trying to insert two images side-by-side in LaTex, but instead of being side-by-side, they end up being on top of each other.

I tried many ways, but none of them seem to work. The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\graphicspath{{./images/}}


\title{Inserting Images Latex}
\author{Lorem Ipsum}
\date{February 2020}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

A demonstration of how to have two figures side by side.

\bigskip


\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{universe} % first figure itself
        \caption{Universe}
    \end{minipage}\hfill

    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figure} % second figure itself
        \caption{Bar Plot}
    \end{minipage}

\end{figure}




\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{universe}\hfill
    \caption{Universe}
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{figure}\hfill
    \caption{Bar Plot}
   %  \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}\hfill
   %  \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image}
   %  \\[\smallskipamount]

\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{universe}
         \caption{Universe}
         \label{fig:1}
    \end{subfigure}


     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure}
         \caption{Bar Plot}
         \label{fig:2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}




\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{universe}
    \caption{Universe}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure}
    \caption{Bar Plot}
    \label{fig:2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


This is how you have multiple images in one figure.

\end{document}
```

What's going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Comment out or remove the empty line between `\end{minipage}\hfill` and `\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}`. The same will also work with the `subfigure` environment. Which of them to use depends on the numbering style you would like to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment has already pointed out, in your first example, the line break is caused by the multiple new lines (multiple line breaks create a new paragraph in LaTeX). It can simply be fixed by either commenting out the line between the minipages or removing the line altogether:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{universe} % first figure itself
        \caption{Universe}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    % Remove or comment out this line
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figure} % second figure itself
        \caption{Bar Plot}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Result:
[image]
The same goes for the rest of your examples, except the one where you do not use minipages nor subfigures.